# Converting character into numeric

Tags: r

How can I convert:

```
x<-c("2.0 lakhs","22.0 lakhs","1.6 Cr", "1.8 Cr")
```

I wanted to assign lakhs=1,00,000 Cr=1,00,00,000

What command should be use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(stringr)
library(readr)
ifelse(str_detect(x, "lakhs"), parse_number(x)*100000, parse_number(x)*10000000)
```

Output:

```
200000  2200000 16000000 18000000
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x <- c("2.0 lakhs","22.0 lakhs","1.6 Cr", "1.8 Cr")
v <- c(lakhs=100000, Cr=10000000)

unname(with(read.table(text=x), V1*v[V2]))
[1] 2.0e+05 2.2e+06 1.6e+07 1.8e+07
```

If you have `lakh` or even `lakhs` You could do:

```
unname(with(read.table(text=x), V1*v[charmatch(V2, names(v))]))
[1] 2.0e+05 2.2e+06 1.6e+07 1.8e+07
```

Answer (score 3):

You can adopt the following approach in `tidyverse`.  It also takes care of the cases when there is no suffix or singluar 'lakh'

```r
x<-c("2.0 lakhs","22.0 lakhs","1.6 Cr", "1.8 Cr")

library(tidyverse)

x %>% as.data.frame() %>% setNames('x') %>%
  separate(x, c('Amt', 'str'), sep = '\\s', convert = T) %>%
  mutate(str = case_when(str %in% c('lakhs', 'lakh') ~ 100000L,
                         str == 'Cr' ~ 10000000L,
                         TRUE ~ 1L)) %>%
  transmute(final_amt = Amt * str)
#>   final_amt
#> 1   2.0e+05
#> 2   2.2e+06
#> 3   1.6e+07
#> 4   1.8e+07
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

add `%>% pull(final_amt)` at the end of pipe if you want a vector in return.